# Amplified piezo sensor wiring problem

Tags: arduino-uno, analog-sampling, piezo

I am trying to amplify the signal from an Adafruit Small enclosed piezo.  The piezo is working using the Arduino Knock example but I want to increase the sensitivity using an amplifier.  The wiring shown below does not work using the Knock sketch and I am assuming it is a problem with the wetware and the wiring(NOOB here). 
Any advice in amplifying the piezo is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand how to wire an OP-AMP. Here is a quick tutorial on their basics:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqCV-HGJc6A

The thing is that you are missing a LOT of resistors. An usual OP-AMP circuit contains many resistors to determine the amount of amplification and more...

The tutorial explains quite well what resistor and where do you need to put them in order for your circuit.